# User defined input csv file

Tags: python, csv

I some lines of code that read a csv file in a certain format. What I'd like now (and couldn't figure out a solution for) is that the file name stops being stale and becomes an actual user input when calling the python program. Now I have a static file name in the code, eg:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))
```

I'd like this to become an information provided by the user. Is this done using raw_input or is there a way to do it by having the user writing something in the lines of:

```
python testfile.py --input:file.csv
```

Appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference the optparse (http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) version would look something like this.

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-i","--input",dest="filename")
(options,args) = parser.parse_args()

thefile = options.filename
reader = csv.reader(thefile,"rb")
```

Which would let you call either

```
python script.py -i foo.dat
python script.py --input foo.dat
```

Comment: Whats the way for user defined output csv?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to write your script like this:

```
import sys
reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
```

and then run it like this:

```
python testfile.py file.csv
```

You should put in some error checking, eg:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Usage..."
    sys.exit(1)
```

For more power, use the bult in `optparse` / `argparse` library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) ([argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) after 2.7) or [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html) to parse command line parameters. Only use getopt if you're already familiar with argument parsing in C. Otherwise argparse is the easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the *argparse* python module fits your depends:

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

The old *optparse* is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `sys.argv` which is an array of the inputs. But keep in mind that the first argument is the actual program itself.